# React stop timeout when useEffect prop changes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, timeout

I'm building and React application, where I have to save on what page of online display document user currently is, but there is a problem, that if users scroll throughout the document, it saves all pages. So we want to use some kind of timer function, that would only trigger if prop page hasn't changed in 30 seconds for example. Here is my code, it invokes later, but still for all pages through the scroll.

```
useEffect(
        async () => {
            let timeout;
            if (scriptInfo && authData && numPages) {
                setTimeout(async () => {
                    const res = await postScriptAnalyticsData({
                        script_id: scriptInfo._id,
                        user_id: authData.user.user_id,
                        page: page,
                        full_page: numPages
                    });
                }, 10000);
            }

            return () => {
                clearTimeout(timeout);
            };
        },
        [ scriptInfo, page, authData, numPages ]
    );
```

Comment: Yeah, I missed that, but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `useEffect()` callback function should not be `async`. The useEffect hook should return a function when a value is returned, but if your callback is `async`, then it will implicitly return a Promise. Remove the `async` from your useEffect callback, as this isn't needed as you're not using `await` directly within the function. Also, assign the `timeout` to the return value of setTimeout() so you can clear it:

```
useEffect(() => { // can't be `async`, so remove it
    let timeout;
    if (scriptInfo && authData && numPages) {
      timeout = setTimeout(async () => { // assign `timeout`
        const res = await postScriptAnalyticsData({
          script_id: scriptInfo._id,
          user_id: authData.user.user_id,
          page: page,
          full_page: numPages
        });
      }, 10000);
    }

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeout);
    };
  }, 
  [scriptInfo, page, authData, numPages]
);
```

Comment: Yes, that async was the problem, (and also that assign, but that was in actual code, I just didnt copy it properly)

Answer (score 0):

Declare the setTimeout() ... , out of the components cause or if it is not using hooks
And keep it in a variable
Ex:

```
const timerCustom = setTimeout(...)
```

// Component
useEffect (() => {
...
clearTimeout(timerCustom);
...
})

and just clear it when your page props changed

Comment: But I also want to save the page when it changes. For example, page state is 1 => 2 => 3, and I want to setTimeout to save the page, it changes to 2, clear it, setTimeout to save page 2, page changes to 3, clear it, setTimeout to save page 3, it doesn't change for 30 seconds, save it